# How to solve the TS type error when trying to get firebase data by using orderByChild?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native

I need to get all the players ordered by their points from Firebase(V9) Realtime Database.
I tried to fetch them as it is instructed in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).

But `ref(db, 'usersPoints')` throws this TypeScript error:

`Argument of type 'DatabaseReference' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Query<unknown>'. Type 'DatabaseReference' is missing the following properties from type 'Query<unknown>': converter, type, firestore, withConverter`

Here is the code:

```js
const db = getDatabase();
const playersByPoints = query(ref(db, "usersPoints"), orderByChild("points"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're importing `query` from `firebase/firestore`, instead of `firebase/database`.